# Вопрос к php кодерам. Рулетки cs:go

Tags: php

Возможно ли прикрутить оплату деньгами(онлайн-кассы) на скрипты рулеток cs:go (пополнение баланса сайта не скинами, а с помощью онлайн пополнений при помощи платежных систем) ? 
Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможно. Используя API нужных платежных сервисов. Как? Это описано у них в документации

Comment: Для этого нужно убирать функцию пополнения скинами и вставлять их api. Верно?

Comment: @user228075 нужно изучить свои скрипты, понять где и как происходит оплата баланса и изменить.

Comment: @Almightily поделитесь инфой, где брали саму рулетку?

Comment: В каком смысле? У меня нет никакой рулетки. Да и в плане логики это не сложная вещь

Comment: @Almightily как нету?